# TransitionSet - Outgoing Activity fades out without specifying it

Tags: android, android-transitions

I have a TransitionSet that should slide everything upwards.

For some reason, the exiting activity fades out before the sliding occurs.

[image]

I would like the menu on Activity A (the three buttons ) to either slide up, too or to stay where it is (so the incoming activity overlaps it).

How can I remove the fade out?

My TransitionSet looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<transitionSet xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="2000"
    android:transitionOrdering="together"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/linear">
    <slide android:slideEdge="bottom"
        android:transitionOrdering="together">
        <targets>
            <target android:excludeId="@id/ivSnoopCam" />
            <target android:excludeId="@id/ivMore" />
            <target android:excludeId="@id/ivMySnoops" />
            <target android:targetName="menu"/>
            <target android:targetId="@id/ivBackground"/>
            <target android:excludeId="@android:id/navigationBarBackground" />
            <target android:excludeId="@android:id/statusBarBackground" />
            <target android:targetName="content"/>
        </targets>
    </slide>
    <fade>
        <targets>
            <target android:excludeId="@id/ivSnoopCam" />
            <target android:excludeId="@id/ivMore" />
            <target android:excludeId="@id/ivMySnoops" />
            <target android:excludeId="@android:id/navigationBarBackground" />
            <target android:excludeId="@android:id/statusBarBackground" />
            <target android:targetName="content"/>
        </targets>
    </fade>
</transitionSet>
```